# android fragment fires itself when using tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have this Android architecture:

Activity that has an action bar with two tabs.

#### each tab is a fragment

my problem is, when i start the activity, the two tabs start working.

I don't want the second tab to start working unless i click on it.

How please?

#### note that i am using

onCreateView on my second fragment

#### note

i tried to make my functions on `onResume()` but still fires itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes from caching of the ViewPager : it will initiate the visible fragment and one on each side (left and right). There is no thing you can do against that. The method [`setOffscreenPageLimit`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29) will refuse a value below 1.

So the solution is to fire your own even to actually "start" your fragment when it becomes visible. Don't use the fragment lifecycle per say, but add a custom method : `startBeingVisible()`.

To fire this custom event, you can just use an [`OnPageChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOnPageChangeListener%28android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener%29).

Comment: how to know when a fragment is visible please?